# Could not find a getter for property

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate with C# and at compiling time it gives me this error:

```
 {"Could not find a getter for property 'idOrder' in class 'FrancosPoS.DBMapping.ordPsf'"}
```

I have found this question, but I could not get how to use it for me:
[Nhibernate - Could not find a getter for property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863837/nhibernate-could-not-find-a-getter-for-property)

This is my mapping class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="FrancosPoS" namespace="FrancosPoS.DBMapping" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="ordPsf" table="ord_psf" lazy="true" >
    <id name="idOrdPastaF">
      <generator class="identity" />
      <!--<column name="idOrdPastaF" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="true" />-->
    </id>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="idOrder">
      <column name="idOrder" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="idOrder">
      <column name="idOrder" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="idPastaF">
      <column name="idPastaF" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="idPastaF">
      <column name="idPastaF" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    .
    .
    .
    <property name="obs">
      <column name="obs" sql-type="varchar(50)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="price">
      <column name="price" sql-type="decimal(8,4)" not-null="true" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this is my cs class:

```
namespace FrancosPoS.DBMapping {

    public partial class ordPsf {
        public ordPsf() { }
        public virtual int idOrdPastaF { get; set; }
        public virtual order order { get; set; }
        public virtual pastaFeast pastaFeast { get; set; }
        public virtual salad salad { get; set; }
        public virtual onTheSide onTheSide { get; set; }
        public virtual string obs { get; set; }
        public virtual string price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My guess is that I'm doing the mapping wrong. By obvious reasons, I don't want to have a idOrder get/set because I need to use the object. (Besides, I'm guessing that the same error will occur at the other ids after fixing this one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the problem is with the < property > "conflicting" with the < many-to-one > relationship:

```
<property name="idOrder">
  <column name="idOrder" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="true" />
</property>
```

We don't need to have this as the many-to-one will take care of the order object (and id).

Found by looking on how to map a many-to-one relationship: http://ajlopez.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/nhibernate-3-part-6-one-to-many-with-many-to-one/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying here. According to the mapping, your class must be:

```
public partial class ordPsf {
    public ordPsf() { }
    public virtual int idOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual int idPastaF{ get; set; }
    .....
    public virtual string obs { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please, use proper spelling and grammar

Comment: If I remember correctly from Hibernate on Java, I don't want to lookup the ID of the others tables and then writing in the ordPsf object by myself.
I just want to throw the entire object of the others tables to the ordPsf and (N)Hibernate deals with the IDs to me because of the foreign keys.

If I map my class as an ID I will loose that, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a property with public accessors, you can [map to a private field](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html):

```
<column ... access="field" .../>
```

Comment: I could not be able to compile also using this option. It says that the option is not declared:
"XML validation error: The 'access' attribute is not declared."
Is not the access field just for IDs? [Mapping-Declaration-ID](http://goo.gl/jbGgT)

Maybe the [NHibernate Mapping Generator](http://nmg.codeplex.com/) is not doing it right and I'm missing the class="" field with something else more [Many-to-one](http://goo.gl/kmlPX). I will keep trying on that and see what happens.

Sincerely,

PS.: I edited because I pressed enter instead of Shift+Enter.